# Populate a Modal with a Axios Request in Vue

Tags: axios, vuejs3

I have a Vue3 modal as a component, that triggers from a Syncfusion Grid button.

Table.vue

```
<template>
    <h2>Products</h2>
    
    <div id="app">
        <ejs-grid id="products_grid"  ref='grid' :dataSource='data' :allowPaging="true"   >
            <e-columns>
                <e-column field='id' headerText='ID' textAlign='Right'  width=75></e-column>
                <e-column field='title' headerText='Title' width=120></e-column>
                <e-column headerText='More' width='150' textAlign='Center' :template="'aTemplate'"></e-column>
                <e-column field='price' headerText='Price' width=150></e-column>
            </e-columns>
  
            <template v-slot:aTemplate="{data}">
                <ejs-button @click="openDialog(data)">More Info</ejs-button>
            </template>
      </ejs-grid>
  </div>
</template>
  
<script     >
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    import { useProductStore } from '@/store/products.js';
        
    import { Page,    } from "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-grids";   //CommandColumn
    import { DataManager, WebApiAdaptor  } from "@syncfusion/ej2-data";
    import {onMounted} from "vue"

    class cleanUpGrid extends WebApiAdaptor {
        processResponse() {
        let original = super.processResponse.apply(this, arguments);
                return original.products;
        }
    }
  
    export default({
        setup(){
            const products = ref(null);
            const store = useProductStore();
        
            const openDialog = (product) => {
                store.openDialogWithProduct(product);
            };
            return {
                    products,
                    store,
                    openDialog
                }
        },
    
        name: 'app',
        data() {
            return {
                data: new DataManager({
                url: 'https://dummyjson.com/products/',
                adaptor: new cleanUpGrid(),
                crossDomain: true,
                offline: true,
                onSuccess: console.log("Done")
                }),
            };
        },
    
       provide: {
            grid: [Page]
        }
    });
  
</script>
 
<style>
    @import "@syncfusion/ej2-material-theme/styles/material.css";
    @import "@syncfusion/ej2-buttons/styles/material.css";
    @import "@syncfusion/ej2-popups/styles/material.css";
    @import "@syncfusion/ej2-navigations/styles/material.css";
</style>
```

Here is the JS from the store/products.js

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useProductStore = defineStore('products', {
  state: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    selectedProduct: {},
  }),
  actions: {
    openDialogWithProduct(product) {
      this.selectedProduct = product;
      this.dialog = true;
    },
  },
});
```

And the productsModal.vue component

```
<template>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>Product Details</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <div>id: {{ selectedProduct.id }}</div>
          <div>description: {{ selectedProduct.description }}</div>
          <div>name: {{ selectedProduct.title }}</div>

          <img :src="selectedProduct.thumbnail" :alt="selectedProduct.title" width="80" height="40"/>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn color="primary" block @click="dialog = false"
            >Close Dialog</v-btn
          >
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </template>
  
  <script setup>
  import { useProductStore } from '@/store/products.js';
  import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
  
  const store = useProductStore();
  
  const { dialog, selectedProduct } = storeToRefs(store);
  </script>
```

In my table, there are actually many more records, and much more detail, and the two endpoints are slightly different, but for the sake of a demo, the above covers it.

When someone clicks the first item in the row, I would like it to go off with axios and get the details from https://dummyjson.com/products/1 then show them on the modal.  But the way I have it at the moment, it can only load the same details as the grid itself, or a different able in full, not on each modal view.

Would appreciate any help please.

Edit:
I feel like this should be close, but it does not trigger.
Updated products.js

```
    <template>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog"  @show="loadProductDetails">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>Product Details</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <div>id: {{ selectedProduct.id }}</div>
          <div>description: {{ selectedProduct.description }}</div>

          <img :src="selectedProduct.thumbnail" :alt="selectedProduct.title" width="80" height="40"/>
        </v-card-text>
        <hr> New Fetched data is here:
        <v-card-text>
          <div>Super Long Description: {{ loadProductDetails.longdescription }}</div>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn color="primary" block @click="dialog = false"
            >Close Dialog</v-btn
          >
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </template>
  
  <script setup>
  import { useProductStore } from '@/store/products.js';
  import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

  import axios from 'axios';
  
  const store = useProductStore();
  
  const { dialog, selectedProduct } = storeToRefs(store);

    const loadProductDetails = async () => {
        console.log("loading additional data");
        // Make the API call to fetch additional product details
        let response = await axios.get(`https://example.com/products/${selectedProduct.value.id}`);
        console.log(response);
    };
 


  </script>
```